# Ubuntu can't be booted

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop (Acer Aspire E15) and I could load into it by pressing F12 during boot up to access the boot menu. I wanted to go into the boot menu automatically at start, so I followed this guide http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html

I didn't see a Ubuntu option, but I saw an unrecognized device that it said was the BootCurrent, so I used `sudo efibootmgr -o 5,1`. Now when I use the boot manager, I only see Windows and can't load into Ubuntu. I've used the boot repair and I've tried reinstalling Ubuntu but it didn't work.

How can I get Ubuntu back on the boot menu?